# Enviar un correo SMTP

Tags: asp.net, asp

Hola que tal estoy tratando de enviar correos a traves de un formulario en asp
pero no me funciona y esto es lo que tengo detras del codigo (.cs)

```
  protected void btnform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
    msg.To.Add(email.Value);
    msg.Body = comentarios.Value;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    NetworkCred.UserName = "example@gmail.com";
    NetworkCred.Password = "mipasswords";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Port = 587 ;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true ;

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }

    catch (Exception ec)
    {

    }


}
```

Este es mi código en la parte de enfrente pero no se que parte no funcione XP,
ah y por cierto tengo otra duda, si tengo mi host service como le hago para enviar correos desde mi dominio/host o como se diga XD

```
 <div class="seven_col_to_one_col">
        <form action="/contacto.aspx" method="post" runat="server" id="test">
            <input runat="server"  required name="nombre" type="text" class="form" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre"/>
            <input runat="server" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" name="email" type="email" class="form" id="email" placeholder="e-mail"/>
            <input runat="server" type="text" name="comentarios"  rows="8"  class="form comentarios" id="comentarios" placeholder="comentarios" />
            <button runat="server" id="submit" type="submit" class="btn_form" name="submit" value="enviar" onclick="btnform_Click">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: ya intente el código de esa pagina, y no funciono xD

Comment: Utilizando el código de la otra pregunta y también tu código, ¿qué error te manda? Recuerda que entre más detalles en tu pregunta será más fácil identificar el problema. Edita tu pregunta poniendo los mensajes de error que se te están presentando :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me paso lo mismo una vez y es cuestión de permisos en la cuenta de GMAIL, intenta lo siguientes pasos:

- En la cuenta de Gmail que estas utilizando, ve a la configuración:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Te vas a la pestaña cuentas e importacion y seleccionas Otra configuracion de la cuenta de google:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Se va abrir la pagina https://myaccount.google.com y entras en la opción Aplicaciones y sitios conectados:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Allí te vas hasta el último recuadro y activas la opción *Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras*
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso deberías poder enviar email con cuentas de google desde una aplicación propia.

En el caso lo de tu propio HOST, solo tienes poner tu servidor igual como lo configuraras en Outlook, servidor SMTP, puertos, tipo de encriptación, un usuario y una contraseña.